# manter apenas as linhas de uma coluna com o valor com Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Olá,

Sou iniciante na área e um dos exercícios que estou tendo dificuldade de responder é a seguinte.
existe um arquivo com varias colunas. Em uma dessas colunas, existem diversos cep(zipcode), podendo ou não repetir. Pra cada linha de cep existe uma coluna de preço(price) das casas. Descobri qual o cep com as casas mais caras e agora preciso encontrar a média dos preço das casas desse cep. Eu consigo encontrar a quantidade total de casas desse cep mas não consigo associar o preço ao cep. Pra ver se fica mais claro mando um print com as colunas.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi completamente a questão, mas mesmo assim tentei responder, se quiser veja o resultado em um jupyter notebook, [clicando aqui.*](https://anaconda.org/sidon/pandas-groups/notebook)

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# Random
rnds=[]
for i in range(20):
    rnds.append({'id': str(i), 'price': random.randrange(200,8500),
 'zipcode': str(random.randrange(9700,9710))})

# Criando o df
prices = pd.DataFrame(rnds)

prices
    id  price   zipcode
0   0   4939    9706
1   1   314 9708
2   2   4554    9705
3   3   5930    9700
4   4   8306    9706
5   5   717 9708
6   6   7105    9705
7   7   6136    9705
8   8   6882    9704
9   9   4364    9708
10  10  2384    9704
11  11  2003    9704
12  12  8119    9705
13  13  354 9707
14  14  3747    9701
15  15  1838    9709
16  16  3287    9706
17  17  7586    9709
18  18  3228    9702
19  19  4483    9701
```

Ok, até aqui foi criado um dataframe para servir como exemplo, apenas com as colunas que interessam para a questão. Agora vamos obter o CEP com o maior valor e um agrupamento dos ceps com os maiores valores

```
# Obtenfo o maximo
prices.ix[prices['price'].idxmax()]

id            4
price      8306
zipcode    9706
Name: 4, dtype: object

# Agrupando os máximos
prices.groupby('zipcode', sort=False)['price'].max()

zipcode
9706    8306
9708    4364
9705    8119
9700    5930
9704    6882
9707     354
9701    4483
9709    7586
9702    3228
Name: price, dtype: int64
```

**Finalmente, aqui deve responder o centro da questão.**

```
# Agrupando pelas médias
prices.groupby('zipcode', sort=False)['price'].mean()

zipcode
9706    5510.666667
9708    1798.333333
9705    6478.500000
9700    5930.000000
9704    3756.333333
9707     354.000000
9701    4115.000000
9709    4712.000000
9702    3228.000000
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

**Bonus :-)**

```
# Agrupando pelos minimos
prices.groupby('zipcode', sort=False)['price'].min()
zipcode
9706    3287
9708     314
9705    4554
9700    5930
9704    2003
9707     354
9701    3747
9709    1838
9702    3228
Name: price, dtype: int64
```

* Os resultados [no notebook](https://anaconda.org/sidon/pandas-groups/notebook) podem estar ligeiramente diferentes, visto que estou usando valores randomicos e, antes do upload, executei mais uma vez depois de postar aqui.

Comment: Obrigado por ter tirado a duvida!!

Comment: Considere dar o aceite na resposta (proximo às duas setinhas de votação)